# docker-compose --env-file is not working at all

Tags: docker, docker-compose, substitution

I'm trying this:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#substitute-environment-variables-in-compose-files

and as stated by the documentation, this is my docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  web:
   image: "${IMAGE}"
```

This is my .env.dev file

```
IMAGE=node:12
```

And this is the command that I'm running:

```
docker-compose --env-file ./.env.dev up
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
WARNING: The IMAGE variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 67, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 126, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1070, in up
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1066, in up
  File "compose/project.py", line 615, in up
  File "compose/service.py", line 350, in ensure_image_exists
  File "compose/service.py", line 376, in image
  File "docker/utils/decorators.py", line 17, in wrapped
docker.errors.NullResource: Resource ID was not provided
[50006] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

Am I doing something wrong?

I've docker-compose 1.27.4

Comment: works fine for me! change your `docker-compose.yml` to have version

Comment: I have version 3.7 on top

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found in Ubuntu `docker-compose` I have to go to the directory directly where all files (docker-compose.yml ... and some.env) are located.
Afterwards it did work.

Solution was only to `cd` into the directory:

```
cd my-folder-with-compose
docker-compose --env-file all.env ...
```

Comment: this thing is so fragile